# Is there any way to force the jest to run the tests marked as xit and xtest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

In exercises done by "exerism", the tests come as "xit" instead of "it". This way the jest does not run these tests.

Is there any way to force all tests to run, without having to change "xit" to "it"?

```
describe('A leap year', () => {

  it('is not very common', () => {
    expect(isLeapYear(2015)).toBeFalsy()
  })

  xit('is introduced every 4 years to adjust about a day', () => {
    expect(isLeapYear(2016)).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

Comment: why don't you just manually change it?

Comment: Search and replace across files?

Answer (score -1):

You can define 'xit' variable as 'it' before the describe

```
var xit = it;

describe('A leap year', () => {

 xit('is not very common', () => {
  expect(isLeapYear(2015)).toBeFalsy()
 })

 xit('is introduced every 4 years to adjust about a day', () => {
  expect(isLeapYear(2016)).toBeTruthy()
 })

})
```